# bash script hangs when iterating through file

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to iterate through a file (a list of databases) in order to execute some sql on each db.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts :f flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        f) FILENAME=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
echo "catting file"
#LINES=$(cat FILENAME)
echo "going through line by line"
for LINE in `cat $FILENAME`
do
    echo "$LINE"
done
```

it just hands whenever i try to cat the file. Any ideas? The file is just a plain text file with a db name on each line

Help always appreciated

Comment: Notice also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `getopts` (emphasis mine):

> `OPTSTRING` contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
> is **followed** by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
> which should be separated from it by white space.

Use `f:`, not `:f`, to tell getopts to retrieve the filename from the argument following `-f`.